# Delete elements within cells of array MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell-array

This post pertains to the "remove elements" operation which utilizes empty brackets, [].

I'm trying to use [] to delete specific elements within a cell. A previous post mentioned that using () rather than {} with [] for an array is the appropriate syntax to delete elements rather than the entire cell. However, this syntax doesn't seem to work (Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression).  My original code is as follows, which utilizes {} rather than () to delete the elements contained in each cell of newinter from the corresponding cell of inter2.

```
for i=1:11
    inter2{i}(newinter{i}) = [];
end
```

inter2 is a 1X11 array. newinter is also a 1x11 array. I used arrays versus matrices because the length of each vector contained within the cells of these arrays is different.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you perhaps add a small scale example of what your data, and goal look like? Something like : `inter2 = {[1 2 3], [1 2]}` and should become `{{[1 3], [2]}`. Also you don't mention what error the example code gives (only what error the alternate code gives).

Comment: Sure! one cell within inter2 could be: [86 56 96 14 11] and the corresponding cell (e.g. i=1) within newinter could be [86 56]. the result i want is inter2=[96 14 11]. in this case, i don't have any preference for order. i simply want the elements within newinter to be removed from inter2.

Comment: Also, the original error was: Matrix index is out of range for deletion.

Comment: I guess you already found the solution, just to elaborate: You were trying to set the 86th and 56th element to zero whilst there were only 5 elements available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment seems that `newinter` is not containing the indices but the actual values however you are using it for indexing. To remove the elements by value you can use this code instead

```
for i=1:11
    inter2{i}(ismember(inter2{i}, newinter{i}))=[];
end
```

Comment: YES! Brilliant. I didn't realize that I was using it for indexing versus an element search. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not near a MATLAB pc at the moment, but try:

```
for i=1:11
    inter2{i}(1,newinter{i})=[];
end
```

Note that if you're trying to remove the *contents* of the cell rather than the cell itself, you've got it backwards. `{}` accesses the contents of the cell, while `()` returns the cell itself, so you should use `{}` if you want to keep the cell intact. See [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/delete-data-from-a-cell-array.html) for an example case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried your code and understand the logic behind it. However, I tried it and received the following error: Cell contents assignment to a non-cell array object.  So, I tried () rather than {} after inter2{i} and got another error: Matrix index is out of range for deletion. This error is the one I got the first time when using the code displayed in my original question.

Comment: Okay, and just to be clear, each `inter{i}` is it's own array?

Comment: inter2 is a cell array with 11 cell pointers, each a 1X110 vector.  even though these vectors are the same size, they will turn out to be different sizes because newinter, another cell array with 11 cell pointers, is comprised of 11 differently-sized 1X_ vectors, each 20 columns or less.

Comment: Along with the info the comment in your question asks for, I would add of of this to your question to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with intersect is definately the way to go if you want to remove elements using `[]`, however in general the easiest way to get the elements from one vector that are not in another vector is with `setdiff`.

```
for i=1:11
    inter2{i} = setdiff(inter2{i}, newinter{i});
end
```

I could imagine that this will give slightly better performance if that is a concern.